# just some beginner level javascript I thought was cool

Tags: javascript, json

I was thinking about design patterns lately, and I had an idea about one I hadnt came across yet (im sure it exists), so I tried to make it, and to my surprise it was easier than I thought. I thought it was cool, so Id like to share it with ya.

```
//pass this object a function, and it adds its 
//biological and technological distinctiveness to itself
var snowman = {
    snowballs: [],
    addsnow: function(snow) {
        this.snowballs.push(snow);
        },
    getsnow: function(index) {
        con(this.snowballs[index]);
    }
}

function squareArea(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

function circleArea(r) {
    return Math.PI * 2 * r;
}

snowman.addsnow(squareArea);
snowman.addsnow(circleArea);

console.log( snowman.snowballs[0](5,3) );//15
console.log( snowman.snowballs[1](3) );//18 or so
snowman.getsnow(0);
```

What practical uses do you think it could have? What do you think about the idea of objects cannibalizing other objects?

Comment: If you were looping through the array of functions how will you know how many parameters the function needs?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad pattern. Basically you are giving methods a non-human readable name. You might as well write your functions like this:

Bad practise example:

```
function x1(A,B){
   // DO SOMETHING
}
function x2(A){
   // DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Sticking it to a human readable namespace doesn't help matters.

However, it can be the first code part of a [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern ;) See [objection.command](http://github.com/bgerrissen/objection/blob/master/src/objection.command.js)